# Producing a colorful table from a CSV file with php

Tags: php, html-table, import-from-csv

First off, I would like to say that I am just starting with PHP so please be kind. What I am trying to do is print a table from a csv file. The first row I want to be bold with a gray background color. The next rows should alternate with white and green backgrounds with text that is not bold. Below is my attempt, but it just produces a table with all bold text that has a gray background

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("acsv.csv", "r");

$green = "#DDFFCC";
$white = "#FFFFFF";
$grey = "#EEEEEE";
$color = "#EEEEEE";
echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0>";
echo "<tr>";



while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {


        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                if ($color = "#EEEEEE"){
                    echo "<td bgcolor= ".$color."><b>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</b></td>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<td bgcolor= ".$color.">" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
                }

        }
        echo "<tr>\n";

        switch($color){
            case "#EEEEEE":
                $color = "#FFFFFF";
                break;
            case "#FFFFFF":
                $color = "#DDFFCC";
                break;
            case "#DDFFCC":
                $color = "#FFFFFF";
                break;
        }
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

EDIT:

I would also like to know how to define the colors with meaningful names to make the code more readable

Comment: You've given your color some readable names already but you're not using them. You could as well use define('COLOR_GREEN', '#DDFFCC') to make them more readable.

Comment: Technically wouldn't even need to do that -- if you use HTML colour names instead of hex, the code still works. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check whether $color is set to "#EEEEEE", you need to use a double equals (==) in your [if statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp), similar to C/C++/C#.  Otherwise, you're just telling PHP to set $color to "#EEEEEE".

```
if ($color == "#EEEEEE"){
```

Comment: Arg.... I should not have missed that lol. I am assigning color to gray which is always true hence I am always getting bold that has a gray background :S

Comment: If you can tell me how to define the colors you get the win.. For example in C i would do something like #define gray "#EEEEEE" so that my code can be more readable

Comment: I'll admit I'm new to PHP myself.  There is a define function in the format define("gray","#EEEEEE") but I'm not sure if it will work in the way you intend.  If it doesn't, I'd keep doing what you're doing and just change your if statement to ($color == gray)  and your switch to case $gray

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement needs to be inside the foreach or the colours will only change after the loop is done iterating.

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("acsv.csv", "r");

$green = "#DDFFCC";
$white = "#FFFFFF";
$grey = "#EEEEEE";
$color = "#EEEEEE";
echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0>";
echo "<tr>";



while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {


        foreach ($line as $cell) {
        if ($color == "#EEEEEE"){
                echo "<td bgcolor= ".$color."><b>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</b></td>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<td bgcolor= ".$color.">" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
            }
        switch($color){
            case "#EEEEEE":
                $color = "#FFFFFF";
                break;
            case "#FFFFFF":
                $color = "#DDFFCC";
                break;
            case "#DDFFCC":
                $color = "#FFFFFF";
                break;
        }



        }
        echo "</tr><tr>\n";

}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your  tags:

```
foreach ($line as $cell) {
                if ($color = "#EEEEEE"){
                    echo "<td bgcolor= ".$color."><b>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</b></td>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<td bgcolor= ".$color.">" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
                }

        }
        echo "`</tr>`<tr>\n";
```